# Laptop with 1 HDMI output to external monitor with VGA

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, vga

I have just bought HDMI->VGA cable. Wanted to use it like this :

```
laptop<-HDMI<------>VGA->monitor
```

So I tried to set everything up and when I start it it says (on external monitor)

```
CHECK SIGNAL CABLE
```

So I did a little research and in most times users all over the internet say "HDMI to VGA is scam because you cant convert digital signal to analog without converter". Is it true? Did I get scammed?

PS.
If it cannot work that way how can I hook my laptop to external monitor when I have only HDMI output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true.

> HDMI contains no analog signal so it is not possible for any combination of passive adapters and/or cables to convert it to VGA.

[More reading and source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/222/can-a-simple-cable-convert-hdmi-output-to-vga)

Comment: cant DVI-A be passively converted to VGA?

Comment: DVI-A isn't HDMI as you know so the question seems to be moving away from OP but the A represents Analogue. So, yes, DVI-A can go to VGA as it has the analogue signal

Comment: So, HDMI-----VGA cable does not exist?

Comment: Eh? Yes, the cable exists, you own one?

Comment: Hehe, yes but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a usb to vga adapter and am able to extend my desktop to a vga monitor.
https://www.walmart.com/ip/USB-3-0-VGA-Adapter-Converter-External-Video-Card-Multi-monitor-Adapter-Support-Max-Resolution-1080p-PC-Laptop-Windows-10-8-1-8-7-XP-Black/126136259